# About binary modes in fopen

Tags: c, fopen, stdio

I already read the [C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen) about fopen access modes, but I don't understand the difference between `"a+b"` and `"ab+"`, or between `"w+b"` and `"wb+"`.

Comment: As stated in the link you provide, there is no difference : _This additional "b" character can **either be appended** at the end of the string (thus making the following compound modes: "rb", "wb", "ab", "r+b", "w+b", "a+b") **or be inserted** between the letter and the "+" sign for the mixed modes ("rb+", "wb+", "ab+")._

Comment: @Jabberwocky next time I’ll read more accurately, thanks :)

Comment: Hmmm, Interesting to use a site called "C++ Reference" for details about C.

Comment: There is no site called “C Reference”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ordering of the mode flags is not relevant. So `ab+` and `a+b` are equivalent.

The `b` flag opens the file in binary mode, which disables the special handling of certain characters in DOS and Windows, but has no effect on macOS and POSIX systems.

Comment: The only difference with a text file is the handling of some characters?

Comment: "no effect on macOS" --> aside from the earlier Macs  [differences between end of line characters](https://confluence.qps.nl/fledermaus/questions-answers/other/differences-in-end-of-line-characters-mac-windows-and-linux)

Comment: @chux I definitely know that. But who refers Mac OS 9 as "macOS"?

Answer (score 1):

The ordering of `b` and `+` don’t matter.  There is no difference.  So `a+b` and `ab+` mean the same thing.

Comment: Can I also write “ba+”?

Answer (score 1):

The two forms are equivalent.

From the C standard C11 7.21.5.2:

```
w+bx or wb+x      create binary file for update  
a+b or ab+        append; open or create binary file for update, writing at end-of-file
```

As for the `b` itself it means that the file is used as a pure binary file, rather than as a text file.